# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths don't work in another controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib, reload

I have 2 viewControllers: in one controller i have `tableView` (that include 3 table view 2 popovers and one default on screen). i have 3 arrays to all tableview and in `numberOfRowsInSection` i return [array count];.

In second controller i have some tableview with another data. and if i select row i download some data and call method `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` for tableView in first Controller.
If i was in first controller and then go to second it works. But if i at second Controller select row and it call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` i have an error:

Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:862
-[ViewController updateCell:], attempt to delete row 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update

And my tableView is empty in first controller. For first controller i have xib but all connected. I saw that `numberOfRows` return 0.

**Any ideas???** What can i do?

Comment: can you paste the particular code that cause the crash?

Comment: there arу no crash only that error in console that i wrote and nothing on my tableView. If i use `[self.tableView reloadData];` its work fine but i don't need to reload all data i need only to reload one row

Comment: NSLog your array and its count while call method reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: it's empty... i think that it don't call model.

Comment: your array is empty? then that is why its crashing.

Comment: it empty if i in second view controller download. if i start at first in init `self.model = [[Model alloc]init];` and it didn't empty.

Comment: i use `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` for first controller. If i use from second and call reloadrow the array is empty than i go to first and call `show` (butto) and it should show me tableView with rows but it don't create i think. but in nslog my array don't empty now.

Comment: Add breakpoints on each delegate and see what happens when you move from viewcontroller2 to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a check

```
if([self.Model.arr count]==0)
    {
        return;
    }
```

So now it's work fine. If array not empty it reload row at indexpath.Thanks Meera J Pai for help!